Model Binding Issues
**Model Binding Issues **
I'm facing model binding issues in my ASP.NET Core app. The same code works with ResourceManagement1 database but fails with RMT database, though both have identical structures.
Connection Strings:

ResourceManagement1:

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=ANAND-VLINDER\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ResourceManagement1;Trusted_Connection=True;Encrypt=False;"
  }


RMT:

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=ANAND-VLINDER\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=RMT;Trusted_Connection=True;Encrypt=False;"
  }

DbContext Configuration:
public partial class ResourceManagementContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Name=DefaultConnection");
}

Issue:

Can read/write data in RMT database only for some specific table.
Operations succeed in ResourceManagement1 but fail in RMT.

Checked:

Database permissions (can read/write).
Table constraints and relationships (appear correctly mapped).
Database collation (same for both databases).
No triggers or stored procedures in either database.
Both databases are running the same version of SQL Server.

Question:
How can I resolve the model binding issues in ResourceAllocationViewModel when using the RMT database?

are you using code first or database first approach?

"The same code works with ResourceManagement1 database but fails with RMT database, though both have identical structures." Hows that's code looks like, then doesn't work, what's in log file? Any error or exception thrown?

I am using database First approach.

How and where can I check the log file

Need to have a look both of your scenario and how you are doing that.
